# All-sizes Network Simplex

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, network

I am currently using Network Simplex to find the min-cost flow to send $x$ units of goods from source $s$ to sink $t$ given a capacitated graph.

I would now like to solve the problem for all $x \in [1, 2, 3, \ldots, N]$. I could run network simplex $N$ times (once for each $x$) but that is proving to be slow for large $N$ (e.g. $N=200)$.

Does anyone know of some optimized way to do this?

Comment: These methods are very fast, so 200 * almost nothing is still fast. Some algorithms allow a warm-start (using an advanced basis). In addition you can solve things in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Try Ant methods / critical path analysis on the problem.

[Ant Method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms?)

[Critical Path method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method)

I am not able to advise on efficiency of these algorithms compared to Network Simplex